# PHP sum foreach loop results

Tags: php, foreach, sum

I have this `foreach` code, and I want to sum the values that it returns, can someone help me with that please?

```
foreach($timel->results() as $timel) {

       $timeDiff = strtotime($timel->end_date) - strtotime($timel->start_date);

       $hours = floor($timeDiff / 3600);
       $remainder = $timeDiff - $hours * 3600;
       $formattedTime = sprintf('%02d', $hours) . gmdate(':i:s', $remainder);
       echo $formattedTime, '<br>'; 
}
```

This code outputs:

> 00:17:20
>
> 00:00:06
>
> 00:00:02

And I want to sum those value and then output 00:17:28.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like:

```
<?php

$totaltime = 0;    

foreach($timel->results() as $timel) {

   $timeDiff = strtotime($timel->end_date) - strtotime($timel->start_date);

   $totaltime += $timeDiff;
 }

$hours = floor($totaltime / 3600);
$remainder = $totaltime - $hours * 3600;
$formattedTime = sprintf('%02d', $hours) . gmdate(':i:s', $remainder);

echo $formattedTime;
```

Comment: thx my friend, i used your code but it didn't work, but a made a simple change and it worked

Comment: I don't know why the pending edit was rejected by one person so far. It should be approved. The OP made the proper changes.

Comment: Hmm, the pending edit seems to have been rejected, but I can't see why (no edit history link).

Comment: @halfer Yeah, lovely ain't it? If this answer doesn't reflect what worked for the OP, it should be modified.

Comment: @RicardoSoares Your edit was rejected and I have no idea why they did. I for one, accepted it. @ D3F, you should have accepted it right away.

Comment: Ricardo can always add his own answer (though, IMO, if D3F was of substantial assistance, this answer should be accepted).